# Problema com flag ou string?

Tags: python, string

Nesse código simples o programa deveria sair do laço quando digito a palavra **quit**.

```
msg = 'Que lugar gostaria de visitar?'
active = True
while active == True:
```

> Aqui a entrada é atribuida a **place** e depois para **word**
>   Logo depois verifica se word igual a QUIT e deveria sair do laço com a 
>   flag para False. Mas o que ocorre é que o laço continua indo para else imprimindo QUIT

```
    place = input(msg)
    word = place.upper
    if word == 'QUIT':
        active = False
    else:
        print("Então vamos pra "+place+"!")
```

> Não sei o que o ocorre, ja tentei usar o break e acontece a mesma coisa

Comment: `upper` é uma função, portanto precisa fazer `place.upper()`

Comment: Dica, você pode usar simplesmente `while True:` para manter o laço e o comando `break` para forçar a saída deste ao invés de trabalhar com uma variável só para o controle de fluxo (torna as coisas mais óbvias).